# gradient background iOS

Tags: ios, layout

[image: gradient]

This rectangular region has a gradient background which is also transparent. Texts can be written on the rectangle. The colour of the rectangle changes when the user touches it. When the user releases it, it takes you to a new screen. How should something like this be implemented in iOS?

Comment: Gradient transparency PNG in `UIImageView` or even `UIButton`.

Comment: Can texts be written on the `UIImageView` and `UIButton`?

Comment: `UIButton` yes. There's button title. For `UIImageView` , you can put a `UILabel` over it.

Answer (score 1):

Use

1. UIImageView with gradient backgroundImage
2. set its alpha to 0.6 -.75 so that background view is visible
3. Use Tap gesture recognizer on ImageView to change background Image when user tap and navigate to next view

Comment: very nice to use Tap Gesture Recognizer. OP wants to display text as well.